# How to get list of delegated mailbox using Graph API

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

How to get list of delegated mailbox using Graph API.
I replaced ME with users, but this gives all other info, but nothing related to delegated mailbox

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. I strongly suggest adding a minimum viable code sample so the community here has something to go on.

Answer (score 0):

If you have application permissions, or if you have the appropriate delegated permissions from one user, it's possible to get messages from another user's message folder.

Please try the query as below:

```
GET /users/{Garth-id | Garth-userPrincipalName}/messages
```

If Garth(the user in the above query) has not shared his message folder with you, nor has he delegated his mailbox to you. Specifying Garth’s user ID or user principal name in those GET operations will return an error.

In such cases, specifying a user ID or user principal name only works for getting messages in the signed-in user’s own message folders, and the query is equivalent to using the /me shortcut:

```
GET /me/messages
```

For more information, please review the following link: [List messages](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_messages)

Comment: Thanks. I want to delegate mailboxes and not the mails from delegated mailbox.

Comment: Hello @Manojkumar

Were you able to find out if its possible?

Comment: Thanks Yuki for reply. But, I am looking for list of delegates for given master user. I am not interested to get messages for such users. In Powershell, we have get-mailboxpermission, similar to this, I am looking for GraphAPI.